# Black screen after bootbox.dialog in mvc view with jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

### The function i have called in jquery for add and update the record

```
 $.post("/Project/ProjectManagement", { PrjDetails: JSON.stringify(PrjObj) }, function (Data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Data));
        if (result.status == true) {
            GetAllProjects();
            var dialog = bootbox.dialog({
                title: '<h4 style="color:white">Project Management and Tracking System</h4>',
                message: '<p  style="font-weight:700;">' + result.message + '</p>',
                buttons: {
                    success: {
                        className: 'shadow mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent pull-left',
                        label: "OK"
                    }
                }


            });

            $('#ProjList').modal('hide');
          //  window.location.href = '/Project/ProjectManagement';

        }
        else {
            bootbox.alert("Error");
        }
    })
}
```

after click on edit button and save changes, i give the bootbox.dialog and when i click ok l got black screen with disabled touch.

[image: Black screen after adding record and added successfully bootbox.dialog]

when i check in developer options it is due to modal.backdrop.in opacity with.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When i searching for this error i got the solution and i answered my question
after click on ok button of bootbox.dialog and i hiding that modal by $('#modalid').modal('hide'); and i hide the backdrop by using this jquery snippet  $('.modal-backdrop').fadeOut(400);

and my error is solved...